# Get list of covered lines per unit test to process programmatically

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I would like to do some analytics on .NET unit test coverage and I would use to get access to raw data from unit test run of the type `[("SerializationTest.DeserializeComposedObject", ["Serializator.cs:89", "Serializator.cs:90", "Serializator.cs:91"])]`, i.e., I would like to see list of lines affected by each test separately.

I noticed there are questions how to get such data in a graphical form (NCrunch), but I would like to process them further. Is there such functionality available anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option called `coverbytest` in [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) that does exactly what I need here. It add notes like `<TrackedMethodRef uid="10" vc="7" />` to the XML output of the tool that marks what codepoints were visited by what tests.